# SSIS package.execute failure when calling from c#

Tags: c#, ssis, package

I have the following codes:

```
 string filePath1 = Server.MapPath(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FileUpload.PostedFile.FileName.ToString()));

FileUpload.PostedFile.SaveAs(filePath1);

package = app.LoadPackage(@"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\UploadApplication\UploadedCSVFiles\Package1.dtsx", null);

 Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult results = package.Execute();
```

When i execute the package, i kept getting failure as the result. 
How do i resolve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you include the actual errormessage, we would have a better chance of helping.

Comment: i printed out the results of 'package.execute' = failure. I tried the package on BI and it was working

Comment: There were errors during task validation. this was the error message i printed out. Any recommended solutions for this?

Comment: There are usually more messages provided before the "errors during task validation" message. These messages will guide you to the task(s) and/or connection(s) and/or component(s) that failed validation. It's impossible to provide more help without knowing more.

Comment: does package.Validate(..) succeed? and if yes, then after executing package.Execute(..), you can examine package.Errors for list of errors that caused failure